# SimController (device simulator window) disappears when I debug my SWF

Tags: air, flash-cs6

This strange problem is happening for a few days, but it's wasn't before.

Knowing how to show/open it would be great, I haven't found anywhere.

[image: When the SWF is finally loaded, the Simulator window vanishes!]

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. The first time I launch with debug - debug movie - in Air debug launcher (mobile) it shows the simulator settings briefly then it goes away, but the app is still running. The 2nd time I try this the app comes up and exits immediately. I have to close flash (cs6) and restart to get it to semi-work once.

Comment: I think this has something to do with logging trace statements to the console. This is why Testing the movie solves the problem - no trace statements are logged. This is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Choose Control > Test Movie > in AIR Debug Launcher (Mobile)